# Powershell giving wrong output after scheduling with window's task scheduler

Tags: windows, powershell, taskscheduler

I have a PowerShell script to check the password expiry date of the a system user and send a mail if it is going to expire within 10 days. Script works fine when we run it stand alone. But it show abnormal behaviour after scheduling it with windows task scheduler. Sometimes it works perfectly fine and sometimes it's not.

Output: Password will Expire in -736235 Days.
Expected output: Password will Expire in  Days.

It always give -736235 days when if runs incorrectly.

Here is the configuration,

1.General tab
- Run whether user logged in or not
- Run with highest Privilege
- Configure for : Windows server 2012 R2

2. Action Tab

   - Program/script: PowerShell
     -Add Argument: .\ps.ps1
   - Start in: D:
3. Setting Tab(Following Options are checked)
   -Allow task to run on demand

   - Stop task if it running from: 3 days
     -if the running task doesn't stop when requested, force stop
   - If the task is already running then following rule will apply: Stop the existing instance.

Please let me know if you need any other details,

Thanks,
Navdeep

---

Script is,

```
$user = Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False -and Name -eq "<user_name>" } –Properties "DisplayName", "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" | Select-Object -Property "Displayname",@{Name="ExpiryDate";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}}

$DayCount = $user.ExpiryDate - (GET-DATE)
$DayAbsCount = $DayCount.Days

$message.body = "Password will Expire in $DayAbsCount Days.Please reset."

if ( $DayAbsCount -lt 10)
{
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpserver) 
$smtp.Send($message) 
}
```

, 
and the script is running from the same account whose pwd expiration date we needed.

Comment: You should post the script code, don't let us guess.

Comment: And if I'd have to guess, I would guess that the script is showing the password expiration of the current user and, when run as a task, it shows the password expiration for (possibly) a virtual account or some other form of built-in account that has no password expiration (ie. the account running the task).

Comment: thanks for the reply remus. and sorry for that. I have added the script.

Comment: What account is running your task? Does it have permission to connect to AD? Typical example would be a "LOCAL SERVICE" account which lacks such permissions.

Comment: Yes, The account has admin privilege, and also many times this schedule works fine.